# Vagrant and Red Hat Enterprise Licensing

Tags: redhat, vagrant, rhel

Our team is starting to use Vagrant for development on Mac OS X machines so we can better simulate our Red Hat Enterprise Linux production environment. Our operations group says our Red Hat License only covers instances being run on our VMWare cluster. How do other people deal with RHEL licensing using Vagrant?

Comment: This is not a site for legal issues.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about legal matters outside of the scope of general software development.

Answer (score 8):

We were in the same situation and decided to use CentOS on our developer boxes. https://www.centos.org/

Comment: That's ultimately what we ended up doing. We couldn't see a way forward that didn't involve paying for tons and tons of licenses for each Vagrant instance we might need.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded basic rhel server I found online and built a vagrant box with Packer for use in Vagrant/Test Kitchen. I'm forced to use various other repositories (CentOS/EPEL/RPMFusion etc) instead of the RHN repos which I don't have access to without licensing. I actually wrote a small chef cookbook to write all the custom /etc/yum.repos.d/*.repo files after initial install. It definitely works for a dev environment. If you have access to different ISOs then you can built whatever versions of rhel that you need with Packer.

http://dtucker.co.uk/hack/creating-a-vagrant-base-box-for-rhel-with-bento.html

https://github.com/xacaxulu/packer-boxes/blob/master/README.md <----a box to use if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

https://access.redhat.com/downloads/content/293/ver=1/rhel---7/1.0.0/x86_64/product-downloads

Have you also checked the developer subscriptions?
https://access.redhat.com/support/offerings/developer/

There is a blog specifying how to use vagrant with RHEL... but I can't post 3 links :(

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proposal (I am using this approach since I am also working with `rhel` `vagrant` boxes for running `ansible` scripts)

Create a red hat developers account [here](https://developers.redhat.com/) (click on register).

Download an `rhel` `vagrant` box from here (you will have to log in with your previously created account.

Fire up your box and `ssh` into it.

Follow [these](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/253273) instructions to register your vm